# Помогите разобраться с меню в joomle

Tags: joomla

Ребята киньте скайп кто сможет помочь разобраться с меню в Joomle! Добавляю не добавляется, изменяю не изменяется голову сломал. И это Админ будь человеком не закрывай тему как ни как за помощью обращаюсь. Или вот мой лучше wayupovich

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле там всего лишь нужно было нажимать эту кнопку JAT3 Clean Cache))
А тот кто мне поставил минус - гори в аду)